# Choose relayhost based on the postfix smtpd instance

Tags: postfix, smtp

I'd like to setup a postfix host (using RHEL 5.4's default postfix, which is version 2.3) with the following characteristics:

- an SMTP listener listens on 10.0.0.1:25 and relays all e-mails to 10.0.0.1:2525
- an SMTP listener listens on 10.0.0.1:2525 and relays all e-mails to 10.0.0.2:25

Basically the challenge here is to use two different relayhosts for the different SMTP listeners.

Is it possible? Is there a better solution to achieve similar behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the listeners in master.cf with the relay host as a content filter:

10.1.0.1:25  inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
   -o content_filter=smtp:[10.0.0.1]:2525

10.1.0.1:2525  inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
   -o content_filter=smtp:[10.0.0.2]:25

I had fun figuring this out!

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely happy with this solution but that's what I figured out myself as well. Thanks.

Comment: What's your objection to it?

Comment: It's not a content filter that I send the mails to... :-)

Comment: ...sure it is....it's a content filter that does nothing but connect to a particular IP/port